# Можно ли отправить AJAX запрос до назначения обработчика события onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/', true);
request.send();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: можно, а зачем? В (однопоточном) джаваскрипте ответ на асинхронный ajax-запрос не будет обработан до возникновения состояния idle.

Comment: Ну, по идее чем раньше отправить запрос, тем раньше поступит ответ.

Comment: @Khipster правильно мыслишь. Вопрос тут только один, что сделать хочешь?)

Comment: Да это обычный AJAX запрос, ничего особенного.